# python how to pass section name in config parser as variable

Tags: python, configparser

```
******testfile.ini file*******
**[TEST]**
val1=1
val2=3

**[TEST1]**
..
..
**[TEST2]**
..
..
**[TEST3]**
..
..

*****testprog.py****

   #!/usr/bin/python

   import sys 
   import ConfigParser 
   import os

   section = sys.args[1]

   parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

   parser.read('testfile.ini') 
   val1 =parser.get('{0}'.format(section),'val1') 
   val2 =parser.get('{0}'.format(section),'val2')

   print "Value 1 {0}".format(val1) 
   print "Value 2 {0}".format(val2)
```

I do have config file which contains multiple sections . Section name should be passed as variable . i am trying the above code but it failing with error "Invalid Syntax".

Error:

File "./testprog.py", line 14
    print val1
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

which obviously i think code above syntax parser.get is invalid. Any suggestions how to pass section name as variable so that it can read from that particular section and display values.

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Python 3?  If so, then you need to add parentheses to `print`

Comment: @TomKarzes no using python 2.6

Comment: All I can tell you is I get the syntax error with Python 3 but not with Python 2.  It's possible you are unintentionally getting Python 3.

Comment: My suggestion is to add the parentheses and see if you still get the error.  If you don't, then you're running Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code should be called by main program like this, it is working properly. And make sure each section consist of same variable names.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import ConfigParser
import os

section = sys.argv[1]

def test(section):
    parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

    parser.read('testfile.ini')
    val1 =parser.get('{0}'.format(section),'val1')
    val2 =parser.get('{0}'.format(section),'val2')

    print "Value 1 {0}".format(val1)
    print "Value 2 {0}".format(val2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test(section)
```